# Max() in sql query

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have some records in my Table.

I want to select a record having Maximum Age

If i write below query it's working fine.

```
Select MAX(Age)
From Table
```

It's working fine. But If i write like this,

```
Select FirstName, LastName, MAX(Age)
From Table
Group By FirstName, LastName
```

It's Not Working(Showing all Records). How can i fix this ?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the maximum `Age` and and compare the result on the outer query's age.

```
Select  *
From    TableName
WHERE   Age = (SELECT MAX(Age) FROM TableName)
```

Brief explanation, the use of `GROUP BY` in your query doesn't exactly do what you want because it is not a filtering operator and does only group non-aggregate columns. For instance you have two records which has the same first name and last name but with different age, the result will be the person with the greatest age because of the use of `MAX()`.

Answer (score 3):

Since with max(Age) you are going to get single record and FirstName,LastName has multiple records.

You are using this together hence it is creating ambiguity.

```
Select FirstName, LastName from From Table where Age = (SELECT MAX(Age) FROM Table)
```

Use this query.

Comment: Wow. it's so simple. Din't get this idea. Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `not exists` :

```
Select * from Table t1
where not exists (select 1 from Table where age > t1.age)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this simple approach:

```
select *
from table
order by age desc
fecth 1 rows only
```

Note that this does select only one record instead of all records with the maximum age.